# How to apply the xenomai kernel patch on debian?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, patch, xenomai

I've been trying to install xenomai on debian and I'm confused about all the version numbers. I'm on Debian 6 (Linux debian 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Tue May 13 16:33:32 UTC 2014 i686 GNU/Linux)

Steps I followed,

1. installed the linux-patch-xenomai from apt via `aptitude install linux-patch-xenomai`
2. then according to `/usr/share/doc/linux-patch-xenomai/README.Debian` I need the kernel source. I got the kernel source via `aptitude install linux-source-2.6`
3. expand the source tree `tar -xvf linux-source-2.6.32.tar.bz2` in `/usr/src/`
4. then apply the patch as explained in the above `README.Debian` by `/usr/src/kernel-patches/i386/apply/xenomai` which fails

   ```
   1 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file arch/x86/kernel/process_64.c.rej
   1 out of 6 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file arch/x86/mm/fault.c.rej
   1 out of 15 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file kernel/sched.c.rej
   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file kernel/signal.c.rej
   ```

Why is this failing even though the above `README.Debian` states `This is intended for vanilla and Debian kernel sources`? I know debian 6 is eol but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> How to apply the xenomai kernel patch on debian?

You can get the required steps to apply the [`xenomai`](http://download.gna.org/xenomai/stable/) patch on the `2.6*` kernel version from the `README.INSTALL` :

```
cd /usr/src/
wget http://download.gna.org/xenomai/stable/xenomai-2.5.6.tar.bz2
tar xvf xenomai-2.5.6.tar.bz2
cat /xenomai-2.5.6/README.INSTALL
```

From the _ *1.1 Preparing the target kernel* _ the syntax is:

```
scripts/prepare-kernel.sh --linux=<linux-srctree> [--adeos=<adeos-patch>] [--arch=<target-arch>]
```

The `adeos-patch` can be downloaded from [here](http://download.gna.org/adeos/patches/v2.6/)

The kernel source can be found [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/)

There is an example:

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://download.gna.org/xenomai/stable/xenomai-2.5.6.tar.bz2
tar xvf xenomai-2.5.6.tar.bz2

wget http://download.gna.org/adeos/patches/v2.6/x86/adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8-x86-2.11-03.patch

wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.32.tar.gz
tar xvf linux-2.6.32.tar.gz

cd /xenomai-2.5.6/scripts

./prepare-kernel.sh --linux=../../linux-2.6.32/ --adeos=../../adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8-x86-2.11-03.patch --arch=`uname -m`
```

**Edit**

The Kernel and the adeos patch should have the same version numbers , the old versions of adeos can be found [here](http://download.gna.org/adeos/patches/v2.6/x86/older/)

Comment: It did work but only with same version numbers. I was able to patch [linux-2.6.38.8](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/linux-2.6.38.8.tar.bz2) kernel source with [adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8-x86-2.11-03](https://xenomai.org/downloads/ipipe/attic/v2.6/x86/adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8-x86-2.11-03.patch) patch using `prepare-kernel.sh` in [xenomai-3.0.3.tar.bz2](https://xenomai.org/downloads/xenomai/stable/latest/xenomai-3.0.3.tar.bz2)

Comment: i applied the patch on the `linux-2.6.32-5` kernel version. can you add some kernel version taht didn't work, please?

Comment: @Kuravih Try my edit please

Comment: First of all it does not work with the debian provided linux-source-2.6 i.e. `aptitude install linux-source-2.6`. It also did not work for `linux-2.6.32` < `adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8` but it did work for `linux-2.6.38.8` < `adeos-ipipe-2.6.38.8`. I also couldn't find a `xenomai-2.11` so I went with `xenomai-3.0.3` and it seems to work. The kernel is compiling now. will update if it boots.